# Call to undefined method EE_Javascript::generate_json()

Tags: javascript, bug, charge

I'm currently running ExpressionEngine v2.10.1. Two plugins currently throw the same error. Seems like something has been depreciated / is broken. The two plugins are:

- Campaigner 4.5.0
- Charge 1.9.2

  Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Javascript::generate_json() in /system/expressionengine/third_party/campaigner/ext.campaigner.php on line 706

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to line 706 in `/system/expressionengine/third_party/campaigner/ext.campaigner.php` and change it from:

```
$this->EE->javascript->generate_json($js_member_fields));
```

to:

```
json_encode($js_member_fields));
```

And yes, this line needs double parentheses at the end, since it's a continuation of line 705.

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate your help!